# Distinct Children rows ordered by a column of Parent

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, order-by, distinct

I've got a query where I want to retrieve distinct `Child` rows, but ordered by a column of `Parent`. If I do the following, I get an error because the column specified in the `ORDER BY` is not included in the `DISTINCT` list:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT c.foo, c.bar
    FROM Parent p
    JOIN Child c on c.parentId = p.id
    ORDER BY p.createdDate
```

However, if I add `p.createdDate` to the select list, I will lose distinctness of `Child` rows, as `p.createdDate` makes them all distinct.

If I use a CTE or subquery to first do the ordering, and then select distinct rows from that, the outer query doesn't guarantee that it will maintain the order of the inner/cte query.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Please tag your RDBMS

Comment: How can `p.createdDate` makes all children distinct? Each child has one and only one parent, so only one created date.

Comment: Unless you have rows in `Child` that have the same `foo` and same `bar`. But then, your query doesn't get **distinct Child rows**, as you claim. It gets distinct foo and bar pairs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to `GROUP BY` instead of `DISTINCT` (the effect is the same) and you need to aggregate the column you want to use for sort order. In this case I used `MIN`, but you can use whatever makes sense here.

```
SELECT c.foo, c.bar
FROM Parent p
JOIN Child c on c.parentId = p.id
GROUP BY c.foo, c.bar
ORDER BY MIN(p.createdDate);
```

Please note that, since you're ordering by a column of the parent table, you may have multiple rows from the child table that have the same value for `Parent.createdDate`, so the sort order within the same `createdDate` will be non predictable. You need to add at least one column from the child table to make the sort order predictable.

Answer (score 4):

As [@ypercube](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/993/ypercube%E1%B5%80%E1%B4%B9) has pointed out on his comments, You can use GROUP BY and ORDER BY in the same sentence.

> ```
> create table parent(id int, createdDate date);
> insert into parent values (1, '20170301'),(2, '20170201'),(3, '20170101');
>
> create table childs(parent_id int, foo int, var int);
> insert into childs values
> (1, 1, 1),
> (1, 1, 1),
> (1, 1, 3),
> (2, 2, 10),
> (2, 2, 11),
> (2, 2, 11),
> (3, 3, 20),
> (3, 3, 20),
> (3, 3, 20);
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 12 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> select   c.foo, c.var
> from     childs c
> join     parent p
> on       p.id = c.parent_id
> group by c.foo, c.var, p.createdDate
> order by p.createdDate;
>
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> foo | var
> --: | --:
>   3 |  20
>   2 |  10
>   2 |  11
>   1 |   1
>   1 |   3
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=8e16f361d6048d489ed518d1ee4dcc34)*

Comment: OK but the problem is (I think) elsewhere. Not they they don't want to see that column, it's that the column alters the results, if it is added in SELECT DISTINCT list.

Comment: But I retracted my previous comment. I meant: *"you don't really need a subquery. You can rewrite `SELECT DISTINCT` to `GROUP BY` and still use the CreatedDate in `ORDER BY`"*.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ ok, I think I got it.